# UITableView viewForFooterInSection only shows after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, footer

I've got a UITableView with one section and enough rows that the tableView needs to be scrolled to get to the bottom. I want to add a footer view which will stick to the bottom of the tableView and always be visible, so I have implemented viewForFooterInSection. Here's my code:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Get footer view");

    if (tableView == [self tableView]) {
        return [self footerRowRightView];
    }
    else if (tableView == [self fixedColumnTableView]) {
        return [self footerRowLeftView];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the footer view only shows after the tableView has been scrolled, but I want it to be visible from the outset (i.e. always floating whether the user scrolls or not).

As soon as the controller appears and the tableView loads its data, I see "Get footer view" in the log, so I know that viewForFooterInSection is being called straight away. What I can't work out is why it doesn't display immediately, and how to get it to do so.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you creating `footerRowRightView` and `footerRowLeftView`? If they are based on UITableViewCell, there is an issue using them for headers and footers. You have to return the `contentView` instead of the cell.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel - they are UIViews created during viewDidLoad.

Comment: And have you checked `heightForFooterInSection:` returns sensible heights initially?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel - I can't believe it. I did log this to check whether they were returning the correct heights and they were, but having just checked again I realised that I had stupidly implemented **estimatedH**eightForFooterInSection:. When I changed these so they were implementations of heightForFooterInSection, the footer started appearing as soon as the tableView appeared. Thank you!!! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you are sorted. Posted an answer for acceptance. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably your height for the footer not being returned correctly.

Check what you return from `heightForFooterInSection`

Comment: thank you!!! As I said in my comment above, I implemented **estimatedH**eightForFooterInSection: by mistake. After changing this to heightForFooterInSection it's all working as expected now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not a tableview's footer.

Simply add the view corresponding to this header in the superview of your tableview and put it at the bottom of it. Then simply reduce the height of the frame of your tableview to fit the remaining space. And it should do it !

Comment: Thanks @KIDdAe. The problem with doing it this way is that the view doesn't stick to the bottom of the last row if the user scrolls further than the last row. If there is no way of achieving what I want using viewForFooterInSection, then I will do it your way and implement scrollViewDidScroll:, adjusting the y offset of the footer view if the scroll position exceeds the vertical size of the tableView content. I would prefer to avoid that, so will wait to see if there is a way of achieving what I want with a tableViewFooter before marking your answer as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @mashley Indeed it's a bit harder.
Using scrolling offset to calculate footer position can do it. Another solution could be adding the tableview in a scrollview (and remove the scrolling on the tableview) and adding the footer as subview of this scrollview when scrolling should bounce and add it to its superview if not.

Comment: If I remove scrolling on the tableView and put it inside a container UIScrollView, will the tableView load all rows at once or will it still only load the rows when they are scrolled into view?

Comment: I'll try it. If I put an NSLog within cellForRowAtIndexPath, I can count the number of times it logs and compare with the number of rows in the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You can no use footer view if you want to stick the footer. Or try with grouped tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few options by the looks of the other answers. Just to add a hacky workaround I have just come up with, I created duplicates of the views I will be using as footers and added them as subviews of my main view, placed exactly over the position of where the real footer views. The views are retained in properties, so that in scrollviewDidScroll I can do the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([self preScrollFooterLeftView]) {
        [[self preScrollFooterLeftView] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if ([self preScrollFooterRightView]) {
        [[self preScrollFooterRightView] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This way the footer appears to be displayed immediately. The fake footer is removed as soon as the user scrolls the tableView, revealing the real footer beneath it. If the tableView is scrolled below the last row, the real header sticks to the bottom of the section and bounces back to the bottom of the tableView when the user lets go.